# How to put 2 'views' side by side in 1 region using the bootstrap theme?

Tags: views, theming

Is there a way to place 2 separate views (mine in particular are in block), and set them beside in each in a region? I am using the bootstrap subtheme and specifically the content region. I am using drupal 7.

Comment: You can place as many blocks as you like in a region. So just place them both in the content region using the blocks page.

Comment: Yes but that is vertically. I am trying to put them in the same region horizontally.

Comment: Add the row col- class via [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class)

Comment: ah, so this is more how to arrange them with bootstrap, which is a different matter. The block class module should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use CSS. Inspect element with your browser, find the div class of the 1st view and use

```
.view-myviewname { float: left; }
```

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ng5mf5xb/)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use CSS to position things as you see fit.  Your views should have specific classes you can target.  Alternatively you could always layout your regions accordingly.